# How to pass argument in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive

I'm working with mat-autocomplete and some reason my function is not working when I select the item from drop down list so I think I need to pass add() function in my select but I'm getting that it's "expected 1 argument but got 0". I'm not really sure what to pass.

Any suggestion,

```
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;
    this.tagService.addTag(this.workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => console.log("added", tag));
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.superTags.push({tag: value.trim(), type: TagType.super});
    }
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
    this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

 selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    const tag = {tag: event.option.viewValue, type: TagType.super};
    this.superTags.push(tag);
    this.add()             //I'm getting error that it expected 1 argument

    if(this.input){
      this.input.nativeElement.value = "";
    }
    this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
    var index = this.allSuperTagNames.indexOf(tag.tag);
    this.allSuperTagNames.splice(index, 1);
    this.mapper();
  }
```

HTML

```
    <mat-form-field class="form" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Select a Super Tag</mat-label>
        <mat-chip-list #chipList>
            <div>
                <mat-chip *ngFor="let superTag of superTags" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
                    (removed)="remove(superTag)">
                    {{superTag.tag}}
                    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                </mat-chip>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input matInput #input [formControl]="tagCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                    [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
            </div>
        </mat-chip-list>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredSuperTags | async" [value]="tag">
                {{tag}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: please provide the HTML code to better understand

Comment: @OAH hi I just uploaded HTML.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass your event to the add() function :

```
 selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    const tag = {tag: event.option.viewValue, type: TagType.super};
    this.superTags.push(tag);
    this.add(event)             //pass the event 

    if(this.input){
      this.input.nativeElement.value = "";
    }
    this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
    var index = this.allSuperTagNames.indexOf(tag.tag);
    this.allSuperTagNames.splice(index, 1);
    this.mapper();
  }
```

to check declare the add function like this :

```
 add(event){
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;
    this.tagService.addTag(this.workspace.guid, 'workspace', value).subscribe((tag) => console.log("added", tag));
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.superTags.push({tag: value.trim(), type: TagType.super});
    }
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
    this.tagCtrl.setValue(null);
  }
```

Comment: thank you and one more question pls. so in the drop down list I have two words Maixs and Chart (backend data). when ever user select from drop down list, I'm getting undefined so by anychance do you why it happening?. when user type either of them and press enter it working fine but I'm getting undefined when I select from the drop down list.

Comment: maybe your type is wrong, try this instead  ```selected(event) {}``` and before access to the event try to do a console ```console.log('my event',event)``` to be sure you get data as expected

Answer (score 0):

The add function expects a MatChipInputEvent event as parameter. You need to pass it an event like this `this.add(event)`.

You should probably remove the divs encapsulating  and  , you may end up with something like this.
`

```
<mat-form-field class="form" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select a Super Tag</mat-label>
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let superTag of superTags" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove(superTag)">
        {{superTag.tag}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input matInput #input [formControl]="tagCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredSuperTags | async" [value]="tag">
          {{tag}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

`